# How to get 2 id from tow column and get all records from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, left-join

```
I have tow table as below
```

FWTable

```
mid uname   gender  avatar          email           psw     dob         city
1   User 1  Male    cat.jpg         user1@gmail.com psw1    2015-05-18  Ahmedabad
2   User 2  Female  Koala.jpg       user2@gmail.com psw2    2015-05-15  Jamnagar
3   User 3  Male    Desert.jpg      user3@gmail.com psw3    2015-04-25  Porbandar
4   User 4  Female  Jellyfish.jpg   user4@gmail.com psw4    2015-06-11  Jamnagar
5   User 5  Male    Penguins.jpg    user5@gmail.com psw5    2015-07-10  Jamnagar
6   User 6  Female                  user6@gmail.com psw6    2015-05-12  Jamnagar
```

FriendsList

```
fid     mid friend_id   friend_status
1       1   2           1
2       1   3           0
3       2   4           0
1002    3   4           1
1003    5   1           1
```

When User 1(mid 1) online, i wan show those friends like.

```
2   User 2  Female  Koala.jpg       user2@gmail.com psw2    2015-05-15  Jamnagar
5   User 5  Male    Penguins.jpg    user5@gmail.com psw5    2015-07-10  Jamnagar
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: SQL Server 2012, i want to id 2,5 when user 1(mid 1) is active

Comment: Why is user 3 not in the result? He is friends with user 1

Comment: No, friend_status=1 (friend) || friend_status=1 (Not friend)

Comment: "friend_status=1 (friend) || friend_status=1 (Not friend)" maybe friend_status=1 || friend_status=0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select t1.*
from FWTable t1
join FriendsList t2 on t1.mid = t2.mid
where t2.friend_id = 1
and status = 1

union

select t1.*
from FWTable t1
join FriendsList t2 on t1.mid = t2.friend_id
where t2.mid = 1
and status = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with all_friendships as (
    --making a distinct list of all friendships, for both directions
    select mid as the_user, friend_id as the_friend 
        from FriendsList 
        where friend_status = 1
    union
    select friend_id as the_user, mid as the_friend 
        from FriendsList 
        where friend_status = 1
)

select mid, uname, gender, avatar, email, psw, dob, city
from all_friendships
inner join FWTable on the_friend = mid
where the_user = 1
```

It looks like you want to show friendships that goes in both directions, not only the people that mid 1 is friend with, but also the people that are friends with mid 1. This should solve that.